# Jquery Deferred for an async function

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I have been reading a lot about `JQuery's` `deferred` object.  And I can see how it works to de-couple code.   I wrote this orignally using Async.js but would was recommended to use promise.

Most examples I find just chain things to `AJAX` calls.  I want to chain an async function but can't figure out how to do it.  I am retrieving a time from the database then using that time as a parameter in a url, finally I would then like to make a `AJAX` call.

This is where I'm at:

```
    var fetch = function (contactId, callback, errorCallback)
    {
        var buildPromise = new $.Deferred();

        var getLastImportTime = function ()
        {
            var querySuccess = function (tx, result)
            {
                buildPromise.resolve("7 oclock");
            };

            var queryError = function (tx, e)
            {
                buildPromise.reject("Error querying database");
            };

            database.open();
            database.query("SELECT EventImportTime FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Id = ?", [contactId], querySuccess, queryError);
        };

        var buildUrl = function (lastImportTime)
        {
            console.log("I do happen");
            var url = "http://";
            url += 'MobileGetChangedEvents.aspx?Reference=';
            url += '&LastImportTime=';
            url +=  lastImportTime;
            url += '&Format=JSON';
                            return url;

        };

        var makeRequest = function (url)
        {
            getJSON(url, callback, errorCallback)
        };

        $.when(getLastImportTime()).pipe(buildUrl).then(makeRequest);
```

Also my pipe methods seems to be called first :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you pass `getLastImportTime` function to `when` helper method, it should explicitly return a `promise`, (but in `getLastImportTime()` you are returning nothing and `when()` is expecting you to pass a *promise*) otherwise the helper could evaluate it as an immediate resolved (or rejected) promise.

This could explain why it seems that function in `pipe` is executed before `getLastImportTime()`

So try to change your function like so

```
var getLastImportTime = function () {
   ...
   database.open();
   database.query("SELECT  ...");

   return buildPromise.promise();
};
```

Comment: ahh ok, that makes sense.  the build url gets the right value now.  should I be using ".then" to try and call make request?  or should i be using pipe again?  at the minute I get "url" is undefined.  (sorry this is my first ever attempt at a promise)

Comment: @CrimsonChin the method used with `pipe` must return a value. From the API docs `"These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the piped promise's done() or fail() callbacks"` http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/ Now it should work as you want, no ?

Comment: try to change `.pipe(buildUrl)` with `.pipe(function(time) { buildUrl(time) })`

Comment: @F.Calderan what this should change ?

Comment: they should be really equivalent, but if his method doesn't work... it's just to try but he should not get an undefined value when the promise is resolved

Comment: buildUrl was not returning a value.  I made it return url and it works.

Comment: ok, you got that undefined on `makeRequest` function - now it's clear